# Sharing Constant Variables between Node and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Is it possible to share constants between react and node - I am running node and react concurrently? For example, I have some constants I've defined on the client side using `export const` that could be useful to have on the server side, but node gives me an error when I try to `const {x} = require('./constants');` because it can't import correctly. Has anyone run into this problem and found a solution?

React Constants:

```
// constants.js
export const X = 'x';
export const Y = 'y';
export const Z = 'z';

// App.js
import {x, y, z} from './constants';
```

Node Constants:

```
// constants_node.js
module.exports.username = 'foo_user';
module.exports.id = 10;

// server.js
const {username, id} = require('./constants_node');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same node environment to serve your ReactJS components you can probably use environment variables for this purpose.

You can use a `.env` file and import it as `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` where you want to use it.

Maybe this question - [Pass or use process.env variable from node to reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760897/pass-or-use-process-env-variable-from-node-to-reactjs) can answer your question.

Comment: Interesting. I would love to be able to understand what's going on with my problem as well and not have to rework much of my project. Great to know when starting a new project though.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of `react` and `node.js` it is possible by using `module.exports`,

`react version =  "^18.2.0"`, and `express version = "^4.18.2"`,

**Defining**

*constants.js* ( directory in the frontend, here react )

```
const var_1 = "variable_1";
const var_2 = "variable_2";

module.exports = {var_1, var_2 };
```

**Accessing**

- *Component.js* (frontend, here react)

  ```
  import { var_1, var_2 } from "./constants"
  ```
- *Model.js* (backend, here nodejs)

  ```
  import { var_1, var_2 } = require ("../../app/src/constants")
  ```

Answer (score -1):

My project is setup as follows:

Node is in project/ dir.

React is in project/src/ dir.

To share consts across both apps, I define them in project/src/consts/Consts.js and can be imported into either app like so:

```
import Consts from '../src/consts/Consts.js' // node
import Consts from '../consts/Consts.js' // react
```